# duplicate elements in object list

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I have a query in my code, where it search one object for multiple ids. In table `PreparationPhytoterapic` contains the following fields: `phytoterapicItem_id` (foreign key), `preparationItem_id` (foreign key) and `id`. The problem is that when a `preparationItem_id` contains more than one entry, it is added again in the list.

I try use `if(!listPreparations.contains(preparationContents2.get(0)))` but doesn't work.

Any idea?

```
        preparationphytoterapicDao = getHelper().getPreparationPhytoterapicDao();
        QueryBuilder<PreparationPhytoterapic, Integer> queryBuilder2 = 
            preparationphytoterapicDao.queryBuilder();
        Where<PreparationPhytoterapic, Integer> where2 = queryBuilder2.where();
        SelectArg selectArg = new SelectArg();
        where2.eq("phytoterapicItem_id", selectArg);
        PreparedQuery<PreparationPhytoterapic> preparedQuery2 = queryBuilder2.prepare();
        List<PreparationPhytoterapic> preparationphytoterapics;
        QueryBuilder<PreparationContent, Integer> queryBuilder3 = 
            preparationContentDao.queryBuilder();
        Where<PreparationContent, Integer> where3 = queryBuilder3.where();
        SelectArg selectArg2 = new SelectArg();
        where3.eq("id", selectArg2);
        PreparedQuery<PreparationContent> preparedQuery3 = queryBuilder3.prepare();
        List<PreparationContent> preparationContents2;
        for(int j = 0; j < listPhytoterapics.size(); j++) {
            selectArg.setValue(listPhytoterapics.get(j).getPhytoterapicItem().getId());
            preparationphytoterapics = preparationphytoterapicDao.query(preparedQuery2);
            if(preparationphytoterapics.size() != 0) {
                for(int k = 0; k < preparationphytoterapics.size(); k++) {
                    selectArg2.setValue(preparationphytoterapics.get(k).getPreparationItem().getId());
                    preparationContents2 = preparationContentDao.query(preparedQuery3);
                    if(!listPreparations.contains(preparationContents2.get(0)))
                        listPreparations.add(preparationContents2.get(0));
                }
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The problem is that when a preparationItem_id contains more than one entry"  How can an id field have more than one entry?

Comment: For example, one row: phytoterapicItem_id - 1, preparationItem_id - 1, id - 1; And other row: phytoterapicItem_id - 2, preparationItem_id - 1, id - 2; understand now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the  `List.contains(...)` method definition it says:

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

I suspect that you do *not* have an `equals(...)` method defined in `PreparationContent` that uses the `id` field entirely.  I assume that is what you want.  You need to have something like the following in your object.  You will also need to override `hashCode()` as well to make them symmetric.

```
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
          return false;
      }
      PreparationContent other = (PreparationContent)obj;
      return this.id = other.id;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
      // if id is long then return Long.valueOf(id).hashCode();
      return id;
  }
```

Comment: Thx for edit and answer! But, my class `PreparationContent` doesn't have field id explicitly! What I should put in place of `return this.id = other.id;` ?

Comment: You need to put in your `equals` method whatever you should to be able to identify duplicate `PreparationContent` objects I guess.

Comment: Worked!! Thx a lot! It was like this in equals: `return this.preparationItem.getId() == other.preparationItem.getId();` and in `hashCode()` this: `return this.preparationItem.getId();` :)